# Minimum should match on filtered query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to have a query like this

```
  "query": {
  "filtered": {
     "filter": {
        "terms": {
           "names": [
             "Anna",
             "Mark",
             "Joe"
           ],
           "execution" : "and"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

With the `"minimum_should_match": "2"` statement?

I know that I can use a simple query (I've tried, it works) but I don't need the score to be computed. My goal is just to filter documents which contains 2 of the values.

Does the score generally heavily impact the time needed to retrieves document?

Using this query:

```
  "query": {
  "filtered": {
     "filter": {
        "terms": {
           "names": [
             "Anna",
             "Mark",
             "Joe"
           ],
           "execution" : "and",
           "minimum_should_match": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I got this error:

```
QueryParsingException[[my_db] [terms] filter does not support [minimum_should_match]]
```

Comment: If I understand your question, you are looking to find all documents with `Anna`, `Mark`, and `Joe` in the names field, give or take 10% similarity? What happens if we have longer names like `Catherine` and `Wilhelmina` that match exactly, and the last name `Joe` is discarded completely because of the 10%?

Comment: Sorry maybe my question wasn't so clear :)

I've used 90% in order to specify a subset of the list. I'm editing with 2.

That is, a document with Anna, Mark, and Catherine must be matched.
A document with Anna, Catherine and Wilhelimina must not be matched.

The main issue is that if I use the minimum should match inside a filtered query I got ' QueryParsingException[[my_db] [terms] filter does not support [minimum_should_match]];'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Minimum should match is not a parameter for the `terms filter`. If that is the functionality you are looking for, I might rewrite your query like this, to use the `bool query` wrapped in a `query filter`:

```
{
   "filter": {
      "query": {
         "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                  "term": {
                     "names": "Anna"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "term": {
                     "names": "Mark"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "term": {
                     "name": "Joe"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You will get documents matching preferably exactly all three, but the query will also match document with exactly two of the three terms. The `must` is an implicit and. We also do not compute score, as we have executed the query as a filter.

Comment: Any suggestions on implementing this in rails using searchkick wrapper.

Comment: Don't use `must` in the bool query. Use `should` instead, because `minimum_number_should_match` only applies to should.