# ElasticSearch Minimum Should Match on 24k+ clauses

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a minimum_should_match in ElasticSearch with 24k+ clauses and am getting the error that the maxClauseCount is set to 1024. I tried doing it with "terms", but [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824588/minimum-should-match-on-filtered-query) said that it couldn't be done this way.

The ElasticSearch recreation (I'm programming in PHP) of what I'm trying to do looks like this:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            "term": {...},
            ...,
            24k+ terms
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know everything is typed correctly because I'm able to get the error of the maxClauseCount, but what I want to know is if its at all possible to do what I'm trying to do without encountering this error.

Comment: The question you linked to does not specify it would work for the amount of terms.

Comment: Also which version are you using ? I can not reproduce it with version 7.17